# Trying to understand the difference between /dev/stdin and php://stdin

Tags: php, linux, node.js

As a simple proof of concept, I tried to share a string between forked processes from node to node or from node to php.

Take this simple php code that should log the output of `stdin` according to the [php docs](http://php.net/manual/bg/features.commandline.php):

```
echo 'test' | php -r 'echo trim(fgets(STDIN));'
```

Working fine, but when I'm spawning the process from nodejs:

#### spawner.js

```
var fs = require('fs'); var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

//dummy stdin file
var stdin = fs.openSync('stdin_file', 'w+');
//write the string
fs.writeSync(stdin, 'test');

spawn('php', ['stdin_test.php'], {
    cwd: __dirname,
    detached: true,
    //to fully detach the process nothing should be piped from or to the parent process 
    stdio: [stdin, fs.openSync('out.log', 'a'), fs.openSync('err.log', 'a')]
})
```

#### stdin_test.php

```
<?php
error_log('php://stdin');
//this should log 'test' but outputs a newline
error_log(trim(fgets(STDIN)));

$t = fopen('/dev/stdin', 'r');
error_log('/dev/stdin:');
//this is working as expected
error_log(trim(fgets($t)));
```

Why is `php://stdin` empty? Is it safe to use `/dev/stdin`? What is the difference between `/dev/stdin` and `php://stdin` anyway?

Note that I have this behavior between 2 node processes too: `process.stdin` is empty but `/dev/stdin` has the expected result.

- [Gist available here](https://gist.github.com/soyuka/9d5f38761e831d20d99b)
- [stdin man reference](http://www.linuxmanpages.com/man3/stdin.3.php)

Comment: `STDIN` is CLI only and has this interesting note in docs `These constants are not available if reading the PHP script from stdin.`

Comment: From what I'm reading, STDIN is ready-to-read handler for `php://stdin` that is only defined for CLI. `/dev/Stein/` is lower level alias for input stream and appears to be Linux or at least POSIX convention. So php://stdin is the input stream to use for platform/interface agnostic scripts as generic (php-specific) handle.

Comment: @Anthony Interesting, did you read this on the php docs? So, this behavior would be exactly the same with nodejs? Like I said, if I fork a nodejs process the `process.stdin` (node equivalence for `php://stdin`) it's also empty but `/dev/stdin` is correct.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.io-streams.php is where I got the bit about STDIN. Googling /dev/stdin is where I figured it was a posix thing

Comment: I've found a neat solution that always work: `"/proc/".getmypid()."/fd/0"`. It's weird that `php://stdin` does not pipe from this fd anyway.

Comment: "always works" is a recipe for disaster. That path still looks like a linux specific handle. And where does php://stdin currently read from?

Comment: and `/proc/".getmypid()."/fd/0` is equivalent to `php://fd/0` (available since 5.3.6)

Comment: Thanks for the shortcut to the fd. `And where does php://stdin currently read from?` I think that's the real question. By always I meant that it works from CLI but also through the forking processus.

Comment: `php://fd/0` does not have the same results as `/proc/PID/fd/0` in my use case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tested with the following script ( `stdin_test.php` ) using:

```
> echo test | php stdin_test.php
```

#### stdin_test.php

```
<?
echo 'STDIN :' ;
echo trim(fgets(STDIN)) ;
echo PHP_EOL;

$stdin_stream = fopen('php://stdin', 'r');
echo 'php://stdin :';
echo trim(fgets($stdin_stream));
echo PHP_EOL;
fclose($stdin_stream);

$stdin_file = fopen('/dev/stdin', 'r');
echo '/dev/stdin :';
echo trim(fgets($stdin_file));
echo PHP_EOL;
fclose($stdin_file);
```

I get back :

```
STDIN :test
php://stdin :
/dev/stdin :
```

If I then comment out the line:

```
//echo trim(fgets(STDIN));
```

I get back:

```
STDIN :
php://stdin :test
/dev/stdin :
```

If I comment out both of the first stdin echoes (and the file handler pointers), I get:

```
STDIN :
php://stdin :
/dev/stdin : test
```

Looking at documentation on `php://input` and how it is one-time usable unless (after 5.6) "the request body is saved" which is typical for POST requests but not PUT requests (apparently).  This has me thinking that they are called "streams" because you get to walk in them once.

Comment: I read about `stdin` beeing a stream that goes forward as you wrote it. Man page are calling these `line-buffered` streams (stop me if I'm wrong). Would it be possible that the `/dev/stdin` matches another process `stdin` if two processes are piping to stdin at the same time?

Thanks for the simple proof that I can rely on `/dev/stdin`!

Answer (score 0):

Rewind your stdin stream in JS before spawning PHP, else the file pointer will sit at the end of what you just wrote.

Comment: This doesn't change anything. To test this, I've set a `readStream` on the dummy `stdin` file with a 0 start.